# Get Application Directory from within Configure method in Startup.Cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

You can't use a relative connection string with SQLite on EF7, so I need a way to get the application Directory from within Startup.cs during the ConfigureServices Routine where the DBContext is configured.

Any idea how to do this with the .NetCoreApp Libraries?

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        //Figure out app directory here and replace token in connection string with app directory.......    

        var connectionString = Configuration["SqliteConnectionString"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            throw new Exception("appSettings.json is missing the SqliteConnectionString entry.");
        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlite(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("xyz.myproject.webapp"));

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can stash the environment in a local property and then you can access it to get the base path like this:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);


    Configuration = builder.Build();

    environment = env;
}

public IHostingEnvironment environment { get; set; }
public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // you can access environment.ContentRootPath here
}
```

Comment: Works great, and I prefer this method.

I completely missed the IHostingEnvironment in the constructor.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I don't get how this works, ConfigureServices() is run before Startup(), so won't the environment variable always be empty when accessed from ConfigureServices?

Comment: no the Startup constructor should be called first, startup is not a static class, ConfigureServices cannot be called before calling the constructor to make the instance of Startup because it is an instance method not a static method. It did change a bit in 2.0 project templates in that now the IConfiguration is created in Program and passed into the Startup constructor, though the old syntax still works as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the application base directory using following:

```
AppContext.BaseDirectory;
```

Answer (score 1):

For a Function App, grabbing the context from the `IFunctionsHostBuilder` object and then accessing the `ApplicationRootPath` worked for me:

```
public class ContainerConfig : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        if (builder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
        }

        var context = builder.GetContext();

        ConfigureAppSettings(builder.Services, context);

        ...
    }

    public void ConfigureAppSettings(IServiceCollection services, FunctionsHostBuilderContext context)
    {
        ...

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(context.ApplicationRootPath)
            ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use dependency injection where you need to get the path.

Example

```
ValueController(..., IHostingEnvironment env)
{
Console.WriteLine(env.ContentRootPath);
...
}
```